# SQL Server setup ends up with .Net FrameWork Initialization error

Tags: .net, sql-server-2008-r2

This happens when I just double clicked the SQL Server 2008 R2 setup. It says that there are compatibility issues and still I can run the program. But after I click run it error comes saying

> Please set registry key ,hklm software microsoft .netframework installroot to point to the .net framework install location

How can I get rid of this?

Comment: Re-install required version of .NET framework.

Comment: I have .netframework 4.0 installed on my computer

Comment: You have to uninstall .net framework, restart, and reinstall it, then restart. That should do!

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem. My error message was

```
Please set registry key
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework\InstallRoot to point
to the .NET Framework install location
```

However, the actual key was different. This code took care of it

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework]
"InstallRoot"="C:\\Windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\"
```

I discovered this by using the trusted
[Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/sysinternals/bb896645).